# Why is my leftBarButtonItem rendered smaller on iOS 11.4

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, ios11, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

In our app we are showing a burger item in the `UINavigationBar`.
We are using the `leftBarButtonItem` as the place to show it.

Here is the code to create the burger button.

```
    let barItem = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "IconBurger"), style: .plain, target: target, action: selector)
    barItem.tintColor = .tintColor
    barItem.adjustAccessibility()
```

Which leads to following result on iOS 11.4 and iOS 11.3.1

[image: iOS11.4]

iOS11.4

[image]

iOS10.3.1

As you can see the burger button somehow shrinked on iOS11.4

I fixed this by creating a custom button view like this:

```
   let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
   button.setImage(UIImage(named: "IconBurger"), for: .normal)
   button.addTarget(target, action: selector, for: .touchUpInside)
   let barItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
   barItem.tintColor = .tintColor
   barItem.adjustAccessibility()
```

Using this version the burger button is looking good on iOS 11.4 again.
But now when going back to 10.3.1 I was shocked because the burger button was not rendered at all anymore.

(Imagine completely black image here)

I ended up writing ugly stuff like

```
if #available(iOS 11.4, *) {
   // show new version
} else {
   // show old version
}
```

But I hope that can't be it!
Does anybody experienced similar or can give advise ?

Additional information: We are using pdf assets for creating `UIImage`s in our project.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Colleague of mine found the solution which I want to document here.

Turns out calling `sizeToFit()` was missing on < iOS11

```
    let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
    let image = UIImage(named: "IconBurger")
    button.setImage(image, for: .normal)
    button.addTarget(target, action: selector, for: .touchUpInside)
    button.sizeToFit()
    let item = UIBarButtonItem(customView: button)
    item.adjustAccessibility()
    return item
```